# Where do I put a conda-recipe relative to my project?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have created a python project that I want to build with conda however I am getting an error when I cd to conda-recipe folder and run `conda build .` that the setup.py file was not found. I've tried moving the conda-recipe to the same level as the setup.py and adding source section to my meta.yaml but I'm still getting the error. Where is the best place to put the conda-recipe relative to my python package?

Here is my project structure:

```
- MyProject/
  |- conda-recipe/
    |- bld.bat
    |- build.sh
    |- meta.yaml
  |- code/
    |- subpackage/
      |- __init__.py
      |- foo.py
  |- tests/
    |- test_foo.py
  |-setup.py
```

Here is the content of my bld.bat:

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py sdist install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

And the build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

$PYTHON setup.py sdist install
```

And the meta.yaml:

```
package:
  name: myproject
  version: "1.0.0" 

source:
  path: ../code

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - argparse
```

And for completeness here is the error:

```
(C:\Anaconda2\conda-bld\myproject_1492545717354\_b_env) 
  C:\Anaconda2\conda-bld\myproject_1492545717354\work>
  "C:\Anaconda2\conda-bld\myproject_1492545717354\_b_env\python.exe" setup.py 
  sdist install C:\Anaconda2\conda-bld\myproject_1492545717354\_b_env\python.exe: 
  can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `setup.py` doesn't seem to be inside the `code` folder.

Comment: @NehalJWani No, it is outside of it at the same level as the test folder. I was going off of the project structure defined by the Python Packaging Authority https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject should the project be organized differently?

Comment: Did you try replacing `path: ../code` to `path: ../../` ?

Comment: According to https://conda.io/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#source-section , `path` directive under the `source` section should point to the directory containing the entire source code.

Comment: @NehalJWani That fixed the problem! Thank you! Did I put the coda-recipe in the correct location in my project or should it be somewhere else? Is there a preferred location?

Comment: I don't think it matters where the conda-recipe folder is, as long as it points to the correct location to the source path.

Comment: ok, thank you! If you want to put that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, the location of the conda-recipe folder doesn't really matter as long as it knows the exact location of the source code.

According to the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#source-from-a-local-path), the value of `path` should be pointing to a copy of the source repository. In your case, it is 'MyProject', so you could try replacing...

```
path: ../code
```

to

```
path: ../../
```

Better yet, make it absolute instead of relative by using the `$RECIPE_DIR` [environment variable](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-set-during-the-build-process):

```
path: $RECIPE_DIR/../..
```

Comment: Don't use `$RECIPE_DIR`; the path is already [relative to the recipe directory](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#source-from-a-local-path). Using `$RECIPE_DIR` will break out-of-source builds.